# Call reloadData on a UITableView from a different controller

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a table view that uses a location manager to grab the users location. In my `didUpdateToLocation` method, i create an `NSURLConnection` to go off to my webservice which returns JSON.

The delegate of the Connection is set to an instance of my JSONController class and in its `connectionDidFinishLoading` method, i need to call `[tableView reloadData]` to get the table view to refresh.

How do i get a reference to my table view? I tried:

```
TableViewController *myTVC = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
[myTVC.tableView reloadData];
```

but it did not work.

What do i need to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you flow, you need to set a delegate for your JSONController to call back to your Controller that is controlling your TableView. Somehow you need to get a pointer back to your TableView, and exposing that as a accessor from you ViewControler could break encapsulation so it would be better to just have a delegate that you set so you could post to the delegate.