# UITableView reloadData from a different controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, reloaddata

Well , my problem is exactly like this one :

[Call reloadData on a UITableView from a different controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050576/call-reloaddata-on-a-uitableview-from-a-different-controller)

The correct answer said that i've to get a pointer back to my controller . 
I've no idea how to do it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), and inject a reference to your controller from your other controller.

So whenever you create your other Controller, have an ivar on that so that you can set a reference to your other controller. So for example:

```
 [myNewController new];
 [myNewController setController:oldContorller];
```